# How to get data in branket R

Tags: r

I have some a string of polyline like this

> `string<- c("[86.68904585,107.69584036]" "[86.68904592,107.69584040]")`

And I want to get the data inside the bracket and put them to a data frame like

> `polyline`
>
> `86.68904585 107.69584036`
>
> `86.68904592 107.69584040`

. How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: Would be `library(stringr);str_extract_all(string, "[0-9.]+")`

Comment: That first line is not valid R code. You need to say what it really is. Is it your pseudo-code description of a disk file?

Comment: oh my mistake, it only has 2 inverted commas instead of 4. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @akrun comment to produce a solution that generates a data frame...

```
library(stringr)
string<- c("[86.68904585,107.69584036]", "[86.68904592,107.69584040]")
stringList <- str_extract_all(string, "[0-9.]+")
dataList <- lapply(stringList,function(x){
     v1 <- as.numeric(x[1])
     v2 <- as.numeric(x[2])
     data.frame(v1,v2)
})
# bind rows into one data frame
theResult <- do.call(rbind,dataList)
theResult
```

...and the output:

```
> theResult
        v1       v2
1 86.68905 107.6958
2 86.68905 107.6958
>
```